# Postfix not properly routing through aliases to php

Tags: php, postfix, aliases

So I setup everything for postfix/imap properly by going through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto and i'm able to send emails to `fmaster@ME1.com`/`root@ME1.com`

however, I'm trying to send an email to `test@ME1.com` then use `/etc/aliases` to pipe that email into php stdin, and my emails are getting returned by postmaster.

the only accounts I have setup on the box are `root` and `fmaster`. Do I need to create a `test` account if I'm only using test's alias to pipe output to php? I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

my `/etc/aliases`:

```
# Required aliases
postmaster: root
MAILER-DAEMON:  postmaster

# Common aliases
abuse:      postmaster
spam:       postmaster

# PIPE OUTPUT TO PHP from test@ME1.com
test: "| php -q /root/scripts/readmail.php
```

the important stuff in my `/etc/postfix/main.cg` (with domains obscured)

```
myhostname = XYZ.members.linode.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.ME1.com, localhost, ME1.com, ME1.it
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
#mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

then my `/root/scripts/readmail.php` is just:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
error_log($data); // just to see if it was successful
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: For starters - make sure you provide the full path to php in your pipe alias '| /usr/bin/php -q ... etc' - second: are you sure you ran `newaliases`?

Comment: that was it.. wasn't referencing full php path.. thanks @thinice

Comment: you could put this in the answers section so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters: make sure you provide the full path to php in your pipe alias '| /usr/bin/php -q ... etc' - second: are you sure you ran newaliases?

That pipe command should work as I use something identical sans the full path part.